# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, recursión, memoria

> ERROR     return N * factmemo(N-1, Memo)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

El código:

```
def fact(N,Memo):
    if N==0:
        return 1
    elif N > 0:
        print(N-1)
        return N * factmemo(N-1, Memo)

def factmemo(N, Memo):
    if N in Memo:
        return Memo[N]
    else:
        Memo[N] = fact(N,Memo)


Memo = {}
print(fact(3, Memo))

#ERROR     return N * factmemo(N-1, Memo)
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: cuando factmemo entra por el else, no hay un return explicito, por lo que en ese caso retorna None. Ya que ese valor lo usas en una producto dentro de fact tienes un error, ya que no se puede multiplicar por None.

Comment: Gracias tienes toda la razón la solución es retornar el elemento del la memoria (Memo[N])

Answer (score -1):

The problem isn’t related to print. When the elif clause runs, your function doesn’t return anything. So you get (the absence of a return value):None

```
def example():
   pass
print(example()) // should show None
```

None(Type) + integer results in an error. Python is not capable of adding these two types together.

Comment: Hola, gracias por aportar. Estás en SOes y todo va en español. Por favor edita la respuesta